# Map with custom formatter in thymeleaf view

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to convert a Map with a custom Formatter.

I created an @LongCurrency Annotation, which converts long values like this:

Long -> String

22 -> 00,22

3310 -> 33,10

String -> Long

3 -> 3

22,11 -> 2211

([Custom Annotation-driven Formatting Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887914/custom-annotation-driven-formatting-spring-mvc))

Everything is working so far. Now I would like to convert a Map with that formatter. Here is some **pseudocode** which should show what I am try to accomplish.

```
@LongCurrency
private Map<Integer, Long> test;

//only to make clear what I am trying to do.
private Map<Integer, @LongCurrency Long> test;
```

A second way may be to use the conversions utility object from Thymeleaf.
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/thymeleafspring.html#the-conversion-service

I tryed something like this :

Controller:

```
 model.addAttribute("test", 3333L);
```

Thymeleaf:

```
<td th:text="${#conversions.convert(${test},LongCurrency)}}"></td>
```

but it does not work.
**Errormessage**: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "${#conversions.convert(${test},LongCurrency)}}"

I would be thankful for help or ideas for one or both ways.

*EDIT1: a "normal" annotated long value works*

Bean:

```
@LongCurrency
private long test2;
```

Thymeleaf

```
<div th:text="${{test2}}" >
```

Comment: Try this for the conversion service approach: ${#conversions.convert(test,T(full.class.name.LongCurrency))}

Comment: Getting an Error:No available conversion for target class, for both annotation and LongCurrencyFormatter implements Formatter<Long>. (with full class name)

Comment: Looks like the conversionService does not find a corresponding converter. You will probably need to debug inside the conversionservice to see why he does not find the formatter. I don't know if "long" and "Long" could influence that for example.

Comment: thanks, i will do this. btw i got a third way (see my answer)

Answer (score 3):

I got third way working for me. I created a LongCurrencyService which calls the parse and print methods of my Formatter-class.

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class LongCurrencyService {

    public static String LongToStringCurrency(Long value) {
        LongCurrencyFormatter longCurrencyFormatter = new LongCurrencyFormatter();
        return longCurrencyFormatter.print(value, Locale.GERMAN);
    }

    public static Long StringToLongCurrency(String value) throws ParseException {
        LongCurrencyFormatter longCurrencyFormatter = new LongCurrencyFormatter();
        return longCurrencyFormatter.parse(value, Locale.GERMAN);
    } 
}
```

In my Thymeleaf I use that EL:

```
 <h1 th:text="${@longCurrencyService.LongToStringCurrency(test)}"></h1>
```

which prints 33,33 as wanted.

**My way is working for me, but I don't if I should accept my own answer.
It is not the answer to my question, how to annotate a map with a formatter.**

Answer (score 0):

In a spring boot project, I created a standard Spring Service

```
@Service
public class ThemeLeafService {
    public String formatTime(Integer time){
        var min= Optional.of(time).orElse(0);
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", min/60, min%60);
    }
}
```

I referenced in my template

```
<span th:text="${@themeLeafService.formatTime(spettacolo.ora)}"></span>
```