# Spring MVC Custom Formatter is not Firing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, custom-formatting

I am trying to get a custom formatter working in Spring MVC. I've looked at several posts regarding this, including: [Custom Annotation-driven Formatting Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887914/custom-annotation-driven-formatting-spring-mvc). I have traced through my application and I know that the formatter is being registered. Since I am confident that the formatter is registered I think its the annotation that is being ignored, but I dont know why.

For reference here is how I register the formatter factory:

```
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry)
{
    registry.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new PhoneNumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory());
}
```

Annotation:

```
@Target(value = { ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PhoneNumber
{

}
```

Formatter Factory:

```
public class PhoneNumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory implements AnnotationFormatterFactory<PhoneNumber>
{

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes()
    {
        Set<Class<?>> setTypes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        // setTypes.add(String.class);
        setTypes.add(PhoneNumber.class);
        return setTypes;
    }

    @Override
    public Printer<?> getPrinter(PhoneNumber annotation, Class<?> fieldType)
    {
        return new PhoneNumberFormatter();
    }

    @Override
    public Parser<?> getParser(PhoneNumber annotation, Class<?> fieldType)
    {
        return new PhoneNumberFormatter();
    }

}
```

Formatter:

```
public class PhoneNumberFormatter implements Formatter<String>
{
    private static final Logger logger  = Logger.getLogger(PhoneNumberFormatter.class);
    @Override
    public String print(String subject, Locale locale)
    {
        logger.debug("formatting phone number");
        return subject + "BOO";
    }

    @Override
    public String parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException
    {
        return text;
    }

}
```

Usage in the view:

    `<tr>
        <td>Phone:</td>
        <td>${workOrderDetailBean.subscriberPhone}</td>
    </tr>`

Image of the debugger:
[image: Image of the debugger showing the formatter as added]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things you need to do:

1. Be sure that your factory is registering the correct types. Use `String.class` instead of `PhoneNumber.class` (assuming your bean is storing the phone number as a `String`)
2. Be sure to use `<spring:eval expression="workOrderDetailBean.subscriberPhone" htmlEscape="false"/>`

Comment: Using the `<spring:eval />` tag was the solution. Thanks Adam.

Comment: @adam-erstelle Are you sure that it's safe? `spring:eval` evaluates a Spring expression (SpEL) and here we are using value from user. For me it looks like we allow to user execute any SpEL expression that is a security breach. Also, disabling `htmlEscaping` looks strange because may lead to XSS.

Comment: P.S. If this value is an input in the form, then you could just use `<form:input>` and it should work.

Comment: @Slava, if the OP is not validating the input before saving & persisting it  (like a phone number) you are right. But I would hope they aren't making that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

From the description of [AnnotationFormatterFactory.getFieldTypes()](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/AnnotationFormatterFactory.html#getFieldTypes--):

> The types of fields that may be annotated with the <A> annotation.

And now look at the example:

```
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getFieldTypes()
{
    Set<Class<?>> setTypes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    // setTypes.add(String.class);
    setTypes.add(PhoneNumber.class);
    return setTypes;
}
```

You should uncomment line with `String.class`, and delete line with the `PhoneNumber.class`.

P.S. You could also simplify method's body to the single line:

```
return Collections.<Class<?>>singleton(String.class);
```

Comment: Hi Slava, I had the line with String.class uncommented, it made no difference. I just left it in the code for reference while I was working on the problem.