# How to register a ConditionalGenericConverter so that MappingMongoConverter uses the default converter when matcher() returns false

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I want to register a `ConditionalGenericConverter` and I want it to be used to convert POJOs to MongoDB Documents when the `ConditionalGenericConverter.matcher()` returns `true`; otherwise the default converter should be used.

I have the model `Workflow` and it has a property `tags` of type `List<Tag>` where `Tag` is also a model. And wrote the class `TagsConditionalConverter` which implements the `ConditionalGenericConverter` interface. Finally I registered the `TagsConditionalConverter` in `MongoCustomConversions` in the `ConverterConfig` class. This works fine when the `/*matcher condition*/` is satisfied (i.e., `TagsConditionalConverter.match()` returns `true`) for a conversion. However, when the `/*matcher condition*/` is not satisfied (i.e., `TagsConditionalConverter.match()` returns `false`), it throws a `ConverterNotFoundException`.

Exception: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.zs.model.Tag] to type [org.bson.Document]

**Model**

```
@Document
public class Workflow {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private List<Tag> tags;
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

**Converter**

```
public class TagsConditionalConverter implements ConditionalGenericConverter {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        if (/*matcher condition*/) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        return Collections.singleton(
            new ConvertiblePair(List.class, Document.class)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        Document document = new Document();
        // conversion logic
        return document;
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class ConverterConfig {
    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
        return new MongoCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(
            new TagsConditionalConverter()
        ));
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest a way to register the `TagsConditionalConverter` such that `MappingMongoConverter` uses it for mapping when the `/*matcher condition*/` is satisfied and uses the default converter otherwise, or is there any other approach to achieve this objective.

I tried the solution in [Custom Annotation-driven Formatting Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887914/custom-annotation-driven-formatting-spring-mvc) and other solutions to similar questions, but `parse()` and `print()` methods are never called - the conversions are done using the default converter. Plus, I do not want a formatter; only want to add a converter for `List` (`List<Tag>`) to `Document`.

Thanks in advance